# How to scrape an .aspx website using R when rvest does not work?

Tags: asp.net, r, web-scraping

I am facing some difficulty in scraping the following website:

https://cps.edu/Schools/Find_a_school/Pages/findaschool.aspx

In the past I have used the rvest package, but with this website, the url does not change when I select "Show All Schools" nor when I select a specific school.

Also, their is no useful xml code to grasp onto to scrape from.

How would I go about scraping this website? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What do you want to scrap? What have you tried?

Comment: I wanted to scrape the school name, grade category, grades, and rating. I tried using rvest and using selector gadget. I would get "#findaschoolFrame"  CSS code with SelectorGadget. Once I ran html_text I would only get "/r/n".

Comment: I don't see this data on site you posted? Text input requires zip code. How should we know zip code?

Comment: Click "Show All Schools"

Comment: Please update to include your current code using [edit]